# "#1265 - Data truncated" error changing column (set) values

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

This error occurs several times, while I attent to change values in a "set" column, in structure mode of Phpmyadmin.
I get an "#1265 - Data truncated" error, *even if the new length* of a value is *exactly the same* than the old one (for example if I change "fra" with "frn", or "gre" with "grc").
I.g. I have a "lang" column (in my table quotations), whose values are: 'it','lat','fr','en','deu','esp','gr'.
I cannot change not only 'fr' with 'frn' or 'gr' with 'grc', but neither 'lat' with 'ltn'. I don't understand why.
I have PHP version: 7.3.7, MariaDB: 10.3.16-MariaDB, and Phpmyadmin: 4.9.4
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - typically you will want to attempt to write some code after researching it online or doing tutorials.  Once you have done this post you code / errors here for support.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution (quite trivial, indeed): the problem was that some records were already with the value I would change.
So, instead than *replace* 'gr' with 'grc', I *added* 'grc' in table structure.  Then I searched all my items with 'gr' value and changed them with 'grc' value.
And finally I deleted 'gr' from table structure.